# What types in C++ are enumerated types?

Tags: c++, types

I found that([click here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm)) switch can use integer types or "enumerated types" in controlling expression inC++.

One explanation for "enumerate" in [this article](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/) is that enumerated types *"are types that are defined with a set of custom identifiers, known as enumerators, as possible values"*.

However, for types like char, int, long, double, since they only use at most 8 bytes, it contains at most 2<sup>32</sup> possible elements. Then all these possible choice of elements are definitely sortable (using the common arithmetic comparison). Hence they are all enumerated types. Further, this argument would also apply to any other types. Then, **what type is not an enumerated type?**

Credit will give to those who can **explain the definition** of enumerated type clearly, and also give concrete examples on both **enumerated types** and **non-enumerated types**.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: The article you linked doesn't say switch can only use enumerated types. It says an integral or enumerated type, or a class type that can be converted to either.

Comment: "an integral or enumerated type" I don't know why you didn't see integral although it's written many times there ...

Comment: Integral types are `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` and `bool`. While enumerated types are those defined by the keyword `enum` or as `enum class`.

Comment: My fault. Sorry for that

Comment: ... and their `unsigned` variants...

Comment: This sounds a bit like "here's my exam/homework question that I'm supposed to be answering, but I want you to answer it instead"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum):

> An enumeration is a distinct type whose value is restricted to one of
>   several explicitly named constants ("enumerators"). The values of the
>   constants are values of an integral type known as the underlying type
>   of the enumeration.

So an example of an enumerated type is any type you might declare using the `enum` keyword.

An example of a non-enumerated type would be an `int` because its values are not restricted to a set of explicitly named constants, but rather all integers (or all integers an `int` could represent given its size).

Another example of a non-enumerated type is a pointer to anything because the set of possible values for a pointer are not integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerated types are user-defined types which, like integers, can take a range of numerical values. They are declared using the `enum` keyword, and typically define a set of named values to specify which values they should hold (although they are not necessarily restricted to those values). For example:

```
enum colour {red, green, puce};
```

declares `colour` to be an enumerated type, and defined `red`, `green` and `puce` to be values that an object of that type can take.

These can be used in a `switch` statement, as can the integral types like `char`, `int`, and `long`. You may have misread the first article you link to, which says "integral or enumerated type", not only "enumerated type".