# Explicitly declaring an enumeration with a type definition in C++: is that necessary?

Tags: c++, enums, declaration, typedef, enumeration

I wondered whether the C++ declarations

`enum colour {blue, green, red};`

and

`typedef enum {blue, green, red} colour;`

are equivalent once the enumeration is in itself a type, as I understood from the answer and references in [What types in C++ are enumerated types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486270/what-types-in-c-are-enumerated-types).
I came across the latter declaration in some code I am looking into.

Do the two declarations differ in meaning, expressiveness (say, clarity) or possibilities they open while coding on?

Comment: This is mostly a carryover from C, where people got tired of having to write `enum colour` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these two declarations

```
enum colour {blue, green, red};

typedef enum {blue, green, red} colour;
```

influences on the name look-up.

For the first declaration even if the name `colour` is hidden you can use the elaborated name `enum colour`

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

enum colour {blue, green, red};

int colour;

enum colour c = red;

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}.
```

In fact for the first declaration you are introducing two names: `enum colour` and `colour`

For the typedef declaration the tag name is omitted. So you can not use an elaborated name.

Also without the keyword enum you may not use an opaque enum declaration. And you may not introduce scoped enumerations like

```
enum class colour {blue, green, red};
```

Comment: It might be useful to explain that `enum class colour {blue, green, red};` allows you to write `colour::blue`. That's why you cannot leave out `colour`, that's the scope name of the scoped enumeration.

Comment: @MSalters In his example there is used an unscoped enumeration.:)